# one form two actions with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, action

Trying to first populate fields with one js button and then submit that collect data with a second js button
I can get the fields to poulate, when I click the "Populate" button, but when I try to do the submit none of the values show on the ordertest.php

Thanks

```
<form action="#" name="data" id="data">
<input type='button' value='Populate' onclick='popContact()' /><BR>
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('data').action = 'ordertest.php'"  value="Payment Submit" /><BR>
Contact Info:<BR>
First Name: <input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='cfname' /><BR>
Last Name: <input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='clname' /><BR>
Email:<input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='cemail' /><BR>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function popContact()
{
var c = window.external.Contact;
data.cfname.value = c.FirstName;
data.clname.value = c.LastName;
data.cemail.value = c.EmailAddr;
}
</script>

---> ordertest.php
<?php
$current_firstname = $_POST["cfname"];
$current_lastname = $_POST["clname"];
$current_email_address = $_POST["cemail"];
echo "current_firstname ".$current_firstname;
echo "<br>";
echo "current_lastname ".$current_lastname;
echo "<br>";
echo "current_email_address ".$current_email_address;
?>
```

also tried

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.action='ordertest.php'"  value="Payment Submit" />
```

Comment: Do you have to set the action property with JS? Does it work when you do `<form action="ordertest.php" name="data" id="data" method="post">`?

Comment: using <form action="ordertest.php" name="data" id="data" method="post">  breaks the popContact functionality

Answer (score 0):

Oppps.

using this combination works, $_GET

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.action='order.php'" method="POST"  value="Payment Submit" />



---> ordertest.php
<?php
$current_firstname = $_GET["cfname"];
$current_lastname = $_GET["clname"];
$current_email_address = $_GET["cemail"];
echo "current_firstname ".$current_firstname;
echo "<br>";
echo "current_lastname ".$current_lastname;
echo "<br>";
echo "current_email_address ".$current_email_address;
?>
```